# Loop through and concat spatial files with Geopandas

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, list-comprehension, geospatial, geopandas

I've been trying to batch process a series of .geojson files for demographic census tract data into into one output GeoDataFrame. All the inputs have the same file shape, shared index/label and geometry columns. For example:

Table 1:

| Geo | Businesses | Geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Census Tract 1 | 5 | Polygon(x,y) |
| Census Tract 2 | 6 | Polygon(x,y) |

Table 2:

| Geo | Employees | Geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Census Tract 1 | 100 | Polygon(x,y) |
| Census Tract 2 | 2 | Polygon(x,y) |

Table 3:

| Geo | Loans | Geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Census Tract 1 | 94 | Polygon(x,y) |
| Census Tract 2 | 3 | Polygon(x,y) |

...and so on.

I expect to get an output like this:

| Geo | Businesses | Employees | Loans | Geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Census Tract 1 | 5 | 100 | 94 | Polygon(x,y) |
| Census Tract 2 | 6 | 2 | 3 | Polygon(x,y) |

I've had scucess doing this for .csv and .xlxs files, but I have not been able to successfully with geopandas. So far my workflow has been the below:

##### First, I set point the .geojson files I want in my directory:

# point to files in data_path directory so we can loop them all

```
files = os.listdir(inputs_path)
files_mo_geojson = [f for f in files if f.endswith('MO.geojson')
```

#view

```
print(files_mo_geojson)
['SBALoans_CensusTract_MO.geojson',
'Businesses_5_9_Employees_CensusTract_MO.geojson',
'Businesses_Under50_Employees_CensusTract_MO.geojson',
'Businesses_1_4_Employees_CensusTract_MO.geojson']
```

##### then i make an empty geodataframe

```
gdf_mo = geopandas.GeoDataFrame()
```

##### and try various methods of getting the output desired

```
#this results in have teh index duplicated for each time a new geodataframe is adhered
for file in files_mo_geojson:
     data = geopandas.read_file(inputs_path/file)
     gdf_mo = gdf_mo.append(data,ignore_index=True)
```

#### or

```
#this results in only the first geodataframe being read in
for file in files_mo_geojson:
     data = geopandas.read_file(inputs_path/file)
     geopandas.GeoDataFrame(pandas.concat([gdf_mo,data], ignore_index=True))
```

#### or

```
#this results in all geodataframes being read in but only the first onen listed retaining values
for file in files_mo_geojson:
     data = geopandas.read_file(inputs_path/file)
     gdf_mo = gdf_mo.append(data,ignore_index=True).dissolve(by='label',aggfunc='sum')
```

##### or

```
#this results in only the first geodataframe being read in
for file in files_mo_geojson:
     data = geopandas.read_file(inputs_path/file)
     gdf_mo = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(gdf_mo.merge(data,left_on='geometry',right_on='geometry'))
```

Comment: Are the geo and geometry columns identical, so you essentially want to do a left join on the geo column and only keep one of the geometry columns? You cannot merge on geometry (without doing a spatial join which you should avoid unless you need to because joining on an ID will be much more efficient), but you could merge on the geo ID column

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I appreciate the feedback. 

I’ve tried merging on the geoid, but it still results with each 1660x4 shaped data frame (4 geo data frames, same dimensions) expanding to 6640x10 with geoid not being used as an index to join on like a merge vs concatenation of the data.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado and the fro columns are labels “census tract 1234”, “census tract 4567” while the geometry columns are actual geometries. But yes, they are identical for each geodataframe.

Comment: I’d set geo as the index, drop the geometry column, then concatenate with axis=1, and finally add the geometry column back. Note that this is just a pandas operation - nothing about geopandas except the fact that you want to convert to a geodataframe at the end, and the fact that you cannot merge on a geometry column. But the merge is just pandas, so all the normal pandas rules apply.